# Apple script for an automator service for pasting plain text in quotation marks

Tags: macos, paste, plaintext

I'm new to MacOS but I could not find any solution so here it is what I need:
I work with a lot of pdf-s while writing and I need to use a lot of quotations.
I need an automator service for macos sierra with the following function:
When I copy a text from PDF I need to paste it to a word processor (mainly scrivener but preferably to anywhere else too).
The trick: I need to paste it as plain text to match formatting of the receiving document. I also need to get rid of all line breaks. And I need quotation marks at the beginning and at the end of the pasted text.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I need the line breaks to be replaced with a space to maintain the continuity of the text. So I need to avoid merging words at the end of a line to the beginning of the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation on [how to make a systemwide service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/MakeaSystem-WideService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH46-SW1) using *Automator*.  You'll want to read and follow its instructions, which goes through a step-by-step example of how to take some selected text and change it's case to uppercase, or what not.

So the method won't be too far from what you'll need to employ to achieve your outcome.

You've mentioned using *Scrivener*, but implicitly assumed that we all use it too.  I, personally, don't, so I have no idea what *Automator* actions are supplied with it (if any), nor whether it is AppleScriptable or not.  Therefore, I'm already limited by what I can assist you with, so I'm going to focus on using another application in this example.

> When I copy a text from PDF I need to paste it to a word processor

So, your *Automator* service will take **selected text**, which can be from **any application** or limited to a **specific application** of your choice, such as *Preview* or some other PDF document viewer.

The bulk of the *Automator* workflow will then be scripted, which I predominantly do with AppleScript.  So I would insert a **Run AppleScript** action as the first action, which will receive the selected text.

This will be sent through and stored in the variable `input` of the `run` handler:

```
    on run {input, parameters}
```

> I need to paste it as plain text

So the first line of the script is probably going to be:

```
        set input to input as text
```

It's probably premature and almost definitely redundant, as there'll be manipulations of the variable's contents in a moment.  But, it's also useful to have it explicitly declared just for when one reads the script back to themselves.

> I need the line breaks to be replaced with a space

i.e. No paragraphs, just one, single block of prose, like your question.

```
        set the text item delimiters to {space, linefeed, return}
        set input to the text items of input as text
```

> I need quotation marks at the beginning and at the end of the pasted text.

```
        set input to [quote, input, quote] as text
```

---

Here's the workflow so far:

[image: Automator Workflow: Paste As Quote]

From here, there are a couple of options with regards to what you can do:

① Put the reformatted text onto the clipboard, as you see I've done there, and then allow the user to simply move into whichever application they wish and paste the text themselves.  If this is what you elect for, then you're finised, and the above screenshot is your completed service, which—once saved—will be accessible from the services menus in whichever application you pick (or any application if you leave it).

But, if you want to go on...

② Get the workflow to open a scriptable application and set the contents of the document to the contents of our `input` variable.  I'll demonstrate this with Apple's *TextEdit*.

③ Get the workflow to open any regular (non-scriptable) application and use a rather inelegant technique of imposing control over certain elements of the application in a limited fashion.  This is slightly less robust than ②, but if it's tested well on a single application that you'll always be using, there's no reason it won't be reliable.

---

#### Insert into a scriptable app, e.g. *TextEdit*.

It turned out to be slightly more involved that I had hoped.  Whilst being scriptable does make it a lot easier, there were specific AppleScript properties missing from the likes of *TextEdit* and even Apple's *Pages*, which meant that regular scripting got me about half-way to where I was aiming for, so had to use some of that inelegance I mentioned in order to get the rest of the way there.  Therefore, I won't bore you with going through how it works.  But here's the portion of the script responsible for getting the highlighted input text into *TextEdit*:

```
    script TextEdit
        use application "System Events"
        use T : application "TextEdit"
        
        property parent : this
        
        
        to receiveTheText:(plainText as string)
            activate T
            
            repeat until name of processes ¬
                contains "TextEdit"
                delay 1
            end repeat
            
            if not (exists document 1 of T) then
                tell T to set D to make new document
            else
                set D to T's first document
            end if
            
            set [a, b] to the value of ¬
                attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" of ¬
                text area 1 of ¬
                scroll area 1 of ¬
                window 1 of ¬
                process "TextEdit"
            
            set character a of D's text to plainText & linefeed
        end receiveTheText:
    end script
```

However, it works surprisingly well, preserving the local formatting of the *TextEdit* document, and matching the incoming text to the local styling:

[image: Paste As Quote (TextEdit)]

#### Insert into a non-scriptable app, e.g. *Scrivener*

So, I went ahead and downloaded a trial version of *Scrivener*.  Sadly, it isn't AppleScript-able, so this limits us in some respects.  Namely, whilst *TextEdit* doesn't have to be open because the *Automator* service can open the app and create a new document if need be, *Scrivener* does need to an open project ready to receive the text.  I imagine this isn't too much of an inconvenience, but from a scripting point-of-view, it was a much tougher script to write and it has the potential to stop working properly if *Scrivener* decide to change their program.

Here's the script for Scrivener:

```
    script Scrivener
        use scripting additions
        
        property parent : this
        
        
        to receiveTheText:(plainText as string)
            tell application "System Events" to ¬
                if not (exists process "Scrivener") then ¬
                    return display alert ¬
                        "Application not running." & ¬
                        linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                        "When using this service with Scrivener, an open " & ¬
                        "project is required into which the text can be " & ¬
                        "inserted.  AppleScript is unable to create a project " & ¬
                        "for you." as critical
            
            tell application "Scrivener" to activate
            
            tell application "System Events"
                
                tell process "Scrivener" to set _P to ¬
                    a reference to (first window whose ¬
                        name of attributes contains "AXDocument" and ¬
                        value of attribute "AXDocument" contains ".scriv")
                
                if not (exists _P) then ¬
                    return display alert ¬
                        "No open documents." & ¬
                        linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                        "Please create a project and try again." as critical
                
                repeat until (count _P) = 0
                    set _T to a reference to (UI elements of _P ¬
                        whose role is "AXTextArea")
                    if (count _T) ≠ 0 then exit repeat
                    set _P to a reference to UI elements of _P
                end repeat
                
                set [_T] to _T --> The text area
                
                tell _T to set value of attribute "AXSelectedText" to plainText
                
            end tell
        end receiveTheText:
    end script
```

[image: Paste As Quote (Scrivener)]

---

#### Finally...

To finish up, you'll want the entire script as a whole.  The individual component scriptlets I've pasted above won't do much my themselves.  You will need to copy and paste this entire script into the *Automator* workflow using the **Run AppleScript** action I showed you earlier.

There's only one optional variable you might want to change, which is at the very bottom of the script: you'll see two almost-identical lines, one of which is commented out with a preceding `#`.  These dictate whether the service passes the text to *TextEdit* or to *Scrivener*.  Currently, it's set to go to *Scrivener*.  Just switch the `#` symbol to the other line should you want to give it a try with *TextEdit*.

```
    property parent : AppleScript
    property this : me
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    script TextEdit
        use application "System Events"
        use T : application "TextEdit"
        
        property parent : this
        
        
        to receiveTheText:(plainText as string)
            activate T
            
            repeat until name of processes ¬
                contains "TextEdit"
                delay 1
            end repeat
            
            if not (exists document 1 of T) then
                tell T to set D to make new document
            else
                set D to T's first document
            end if
            
            set [a, b] to the value of ¬
                attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" of ¬
                text area 1 of ¬
                scroll area 1 of ¬
                window 1 of ¬
                process "TextEdit"
            
            set character a of D's text to plainText & linefeed
        end receiveTheText:
    end script

    script Scrivener
        use scripting additions
        
        property parent : this
        
        
        to receiveTheText:(plainText as string)
            tell application "System Events" to ¬
                if not (exists process "Scrivener") then ¬
                    return display alert ¬
                        "Application not running." & ¬
                        linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                        "When using this service with Scrivener, an open " & ¬
                        "project is required into which the text can be " & ¬
                        "inserted.  AppleScript is unable to create a project " & ¬
                        "for you." as critical
            
            tell application "Scrivener" to activate
            
            tell application "System Events"
                
                tell process "Scrivener" to set _P to ¬
                    a reference to (first window whose ¬
                        name of attributes contains "AXDocument" and ¬
                        value of attribute "AXDocument" contains ".scriv")
                
                if not (exists _P) then ¬
                    return display alert ¬
                        "No open documents." & ¬
                        linefeed & linefeed & ¬
                        "Please create a project and try again." as critical
                
                repeat until (count _P) = 0
                    set _T to a reference to (UI elements of _P ¬
                        whose role is "AXTextArea")
                    if (count _T) ≠ 0 then exit repeat
                    set _P to a reference to UI elements of _P
                end repeat
                
                set [_T] to _T --> The text area
                
                tell _T to set value of attribute "AXSelectedText" to plainText
                
            end tell
        end receiveTheText:
    end script
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    on run {input, parameters}
        set input to input as text
        
        set the text item delimiters to {space, linefeed, return}
        set input to the text items of input as text
        set input to [quote, input, quote] as text
        
        # tell TextEdit to receiveTheText:input
        tell Scrivener to receiveTheText:input
    end run
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------END
```

Comment: @Akos Give it a try and let me know if there are any problems I can fix for you.  Then consider marking this as the selected answer.

Comment: Hi CJK! Thank you very much! Everything works great as I use your guide until the "But, if you want to go on..." point. What I needed is a quotation in a scrivener document that I am already working on and your trick is really helpful. 2 things could make it even better 1. the service does not work when I select a text in adobe acrobat reader DC (it does not get the text to clipboard apparently) only if the pdf is opened in scrivener and 2. matching style with the receiving scrivener document would be a nice addition. None of these were mentioned before so my bad.

Comment: **1)** What do you mean, _"a quotation in Scrivener"_ ?  Are you talking about surrounding them in quote marks, which is already done, or is it something else ?  **2)** The script **will** insert the new text into the *Scrivener* document that you are currently working on.  It also matches the style, as you can see from the GIF animation I inserted, where the pasted text—originally black and small—matches the large blue lettering of the *Scrivener* paragraph into which it's inserted.  **3)** What do you mean about the clipboard ?